# How to update DialogFragment's UI from Activity

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, fragment

In the Activity, there is a button (Download) for downloading a image/file. onClick the button, the dialog fragment will be shown with a textview (and an animation) indicating the system is downloading file.

Once the downloading process is finished,  the UI(the textview) in the dialog fragment will be updated to indicate something like "download finished".

My question is: if user clicked BACK before downloading finished, the dialog fragment will be disappeared, and if user click on the (Download) button in the Activity again, a new dialog fragment will popup as well, but UI will not be updated even after downloading process.

I am pretty new to coding, so the question maybe dumb. I googled for two days but couldn't find an anwser. Hope you could help me with the problem.

Comment: Use ViewModel , create a sharedViewModel for the same and save the progress

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I solved this problem with ViewModel.

Comment: Happy it helped